# NumPy: two-dimensional array from one-dimesional

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose we have two  integer 1D arrays `a,b` with the same lenghts and we need to create 2D array `c`  by the rule

`c[i,j]=a[i]+b[j]`

How to do it in Numpy without any loops?

I tried to do it  with lambda function

```
np.fromfunction(lambda i,j: a[i]+b[j], (len(a),len(a))
```

but get the mistake

```
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

The same error and for

```
 np.fromfunction(lambda i,j: int(a[i])+int(b[j]), (len(a),len(a))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: your rule has a wrong index: I believe it should be `a[i]+b[j]`

Comment: @Michael Pruglo, yes, of cource, thank you

Comment: `np.fromfunction(lambda i,j: a[i]+b[j], (len(a),len(b)), dtype=int)`

Comment: yes, as Michael said - you forgot dtype: by default it is float, and cannot be used as an index

Comment: `a[:,None] + b`

Comment: ... or `a[:, np.newaxis] + b`